# Python - Flask is not recognized, after imported

Tags: python, rest, api, flask

I'm trying to create a `rest api` with `python-flask` by following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_ht4AKnWZg

However, after installing `flask` with: `pip3 install flask`, and executing it in the console with: `python app.py` and `py app.py`, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
PS C:\Users\THEROG\Desktop\products-restapi>
```

This is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

Here is the screen of the output:
[image]

Comment: Are you starting you program with the right python version? You can have multiple python3 versions installed.
How do you execute your program?

Comment: please install flask again pip3 install flask and then check your python version make sure it is 3  and flask version

Comment: @NameVergessen I tried with vcs terminal and cmd the following commands: "python app.py" and "py app.py"

Comment: @AlokMishra I checked in the cmd with python -V , and is Python 2.7.17, it supposue to be 3.x  right?, I do have the 3.8 installed , i assume here is the problem?

Comment: @DiegoVenteSeminario yes, and install flask using pip install flask because you are using 2.7 version

Comment: @AlokMishra I just did that , throws me an error, in the script  " File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)" - this is a part of it

Comment: try `pyton3 app.py`or 'python3.x app.py'
or python3 -m app or python3.x -m app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in jupyter notebook: copy and paste it in Your file

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

if code is working open your browser and type `http://127.0.0.1:5000`

[image]

Comment: This answer does not address the problem in the question.

Comment: For me is not showing any line like yours "127.0.0.1 -  - ....... GET/ HTTP/ ", it just dont show anything, take a look:
PS C:\Users\THEROG\Desktop\products-restapi> python app.py
PS C:\Users\THEROG\Desktop\products-restapi> python app.py
PS C:\Users\THEROG\Desktop\products-restapi> python app.py

Comment: I am trying to solve his problem but you are not buddy

Comment: @DiegoVenteSeminario can you share your screen with me if it is possible? after fixing your issue we will update that problem and cure here because someone already downvoted me ;(

Comment: @AlokMishra Yeah sure I dont know why someone down vote? ,can you explain me how to post my screen here?, I can only see the option to comment your response which seems to not support images

Comment: @DiegoVenteSeminario you can't post images here. Can you edit your question with some screenshot?

Comment: @AlokMishra Its done would you chek please?, and if anything else is needed let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try python3 app.py . Also if you are worried about multiple python versions (although you shouldn't have to be since python 2.7 reaches EOL 31 December 2019), you can also use https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/ to manage different environments.

Comment: I try this but , python3 its not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Try:
try `pyton3 app.py`or `python3.x app.py`
or `python3 -m app` or `python3.x -m app`

The -m variances start the module not the script. (Nessesary if you have a main that is not in your projects root folder.)

Alternativly try checking what interpreter is configures for MVS.